# Regex for splitting params out using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am currently using this regex:

`/([-0-9]+).([-0-9]+).([-0-9]+).([-0-9]+).(.*?).([-0-9]).([-0-9]+).([-0-9.]+).([-0-9.]+).([-0-9.]+).*/i`

to match this kind of thing:

`1 0 61 12345678 sierra007^7 0 0 123.123.123.123:524 26429 25000`

The problem I am having is that the name `sierra007^7` actually comes out as `sierr` and then everything after it is broken. What I need is for the `.*?` part to match anything then carry on splitting it up afterwards. If change the `.*?` to `.*` it puts the rest of the information ito the same parameter.

Can someone lend some advice please?

Thanks.

Comment: What possible values can the `sierra007^7` contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I don't really see what you need, but why not just use [**`explode()`**](http://www.php.net/explode) to split your string ?

For example, this portion of code :

```
$str = '1 0 61 12345678 sierra007^7 0 0 90.199.42.51:524 26429 25000';
$array = explode(' ', $str);
var_dump($array);
```

Would get you :

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '61' (length=2)
  3 => string '12345678' (length=8)
  4 => string 'sierra007^7' (length=11)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => string '0' (length=1)
  7 => string '90.199.42.51:524' (length=16)
  8 => string '26429' (length=5)
  9 => string '25000' (length=5)
```

Comment: Valid as always: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: This was an existing piece of code I "inherited" no idea why I didn't think to use explode instead :) Thanks. Will accept when I am allowed.

Comment: @nfechner: ...and worn out as ever. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `(.*?)` use `[^ ]+` this should be much faster and work as you indended.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the original poster has an accepted solution (which works very well), but allow me to answer the specific question of why the regex wasn't working. The problem is the use of the dot `.` - and this is a very commonly made mistake. The dot is a wildcard that is rarely needed or appropriate. In this case the dot is being used to separate a bunch of groups of digits. But the data suggests that these fields are separated with spaces. The solution is simple; instead of the dot, separate the fields with whitespace. Also the dot is being used in the form of a *lazy-dot-star* expression, which is also inappropriate in this case. Here is how I would write this regex (in verbose mode with comments):

```
$re = '/
    ^               # Anchor to start of line.
    ([-0-9]+)  \s+  # $1: Field 1
    ([-0-9]+)  \s+  # $2: Field 2
    ([-0-9]+)  \s+  # $3: Field 3
    ([-0-9]+)  \s+  # $4: Field 4
    (\S+)      \s+  # $5: Field 5
    ([-0-9])   \s+  # $6: Field 6
    ([-0-9]+)  \s+  # $7: Field 7
    ([-0-9.:]+)\s+  # $8: Field 8
    ([-0-9.]+) \s+  # $9: Field 9
    ([-0-9.]+)      # $10: Field 10
    /mx';
```

This regex is much more precise and will match (and fail to match) much faster as a result.

Another problem with the original regex is that the data in field #8 of the example string contains a colon, which is not specified in the eighth regex expression, (i.e. the `"sierr"` was not the only field being mis-matched.)

Note that the regex solution has the advantage that it can pick out matching records from within a larger body of text having mixed, variable format, where the explode solution requires that each string have a known, fixed valid format (which is probably the case here, so the explode solution is to be preferred).

Comment: Is there any way to modify this to allow spaces in Field 5 ?

Comment: @webnoob: Certainly, its very easy. I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!