# Splitting string on spaces but allow a space in 1 field using regex

Tags: php, regex

This is kind of a follow on from this post: [Regex for splitting params out using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693551/regex-for-splitting-params-out-using-preg-match/5694644#5694644)

I have this string `1 0 61 12345678 sierra007^7 0 0 123.123.123.123:524 26429 25000` and I need to get each element. It was suggested I use explode which was a great simple solution but now I need to allow spaces in one of the fields.

Someone else posted this regex:

`/^([-0-9]+)\s+([-0-9]+)\s+([-0-9]+)\s+([-0-9]+)\s+(\S+)\s+([-0-9])\s+([-0-9]+)\s+([-0-9.:]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)/mx`

That does everything else and I was wondering if it could be modified to allow spaces in field 5 (`sierra007^7`). The only advice I can offer is that the rest of the fields are always numeric (or a colon as you can see) before and after field 5. Is this possible with 1 regex statement or do I need to parse it in PHP and fudge it together?

EDIT: For example, field 5 could be `sierra007^7` OR `si erra007^7` or `si er ra007^7`. It would know that it came across field 5 as its the only one that contains a-zA-Z characters. It would know where field 5 ends because field 6 only contains 0-9 characters.

Thanks.

Comment: what are the possible locations of spaces in field five... please provide examples

Comment: What do you mean "allow spaces"? How do you want the regex to know where field 5 ends and field 6 begins?

Comment: I would use `$arr = explode(' ', trim($str));` and count the result array's elements `$i = count($arr);`. Then `if($i > 10) {
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i-10; $j++) {
        $field5[] = $arr[4+$j];
    }
    $field5 = implode(' ', $field5);
} else {
    $field5 = $arr[4];
}` which will create a string containing all the elements that should be in field 5 with spaces allowed... Demo here: http://codepad.org/UoGyoZh4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of fields never changes, and there's always a value for each field, you can do it using code below:

```
$fields = explode (' ', $str);
$defaultNumFields = 10;
if (count($fields) > $defaultNumFields) {
    for ($i = 5; $i < (count($fields) - $defaultNumFields) + 5; $i++) {
        $field[4] .= ' '.$field[$i];
        unset($field[$i]);
    }
}
$fields = array_values($fields);
```

That should do it. I might have mis-calcuated and you might need to change the +4 to a +5, test it on a few strings and let me know.

Comment: Also you can use `array_slice($array, $offset, $length)` function to get a range of array values

Comment: Ah :P hehe. No problem... yeah figured my math might just be a little off!

Answer (score 4):

Why not use explode, like the other thread. And count the number of items in the array. If more items are in the array, you put item 5 + any number too high together again with implode..
Eg. your normal row has 10 items. If the resulting explode has 15 items, you:

```
implode(" ",array_slice($array,5,(count($array)-10)));
```

Comment: That would be hard to manage if field 5 contains more that 1 space and I need access to all the fields after field 5 separatly.

Comment: Added an example code.  Take a look at SkippyChalmers, his example is doing the same as what I proposed.